# Attempting to reference a deleted function in objects factory

Tags: c++, oop, templates, factory-pattern

I get next error, when compining code.

```
Error   C2280   'Square::Square(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function  objectfactory.h 11
```

I have next object factory, for objects:

```
template<class ID, class Base, class ... Args> class GenericObjectFactory {
private:
    typedef Base* (*fInstantiator)(Args ...);
    template<class Derived> static Base* instantiator(Args ... args) {
        return new Derived(args ...);
    }
    std::map<ID, fInstantiator> classes;

public:
    GenericObjectFactory() {}
    template<class Derived> void add(ID id) {
        classes[id] = &instantiator<Derived>;
    }
    fInstantiator get(ID id) {
        return classes[id];
    }
};
```

Base class for example:

```
class BaseFigure
{
private:
    BaseFigure(const BaseFigure&);
    int m_params_num;
public:
    BaseFigure() : m_params_num(0) {};
    virtual void draw(WDraw &drawer)=0;
    virtual void boundingBox(WDraw &drawer) = 0;
    virtual ~BaseFigure() {};
};
```

And derived class from BaseFigure:

```
class Square :
    public BaseFigure
{
private:
    Point2d points[2];
public:
    std::string type();
    void draw(WDraw &drawer);
    void boundingBox(WDraw &drawer);
    ~Square();
};
```

Square realization below:

```
 void Square::draw(WDraw &drawer) {
    Point2d cournerSecond(points[0].x(), points[1].y()), cournerFour(points[1].x(), points[0].y());
    drawer.drawSegment(points[0], cournerSecond);
    drawer.drawSegment(cournerSecond, points[1]);
    drawer.drawSegment(points[1], cournerFour);
    drawer.drawSegment(cournerFour, points[0]);
}
void Square::boundingBox(WDraw &drawer) {
    this->boundingBox(drawer);
}
```

Example of using:

```
GenericObjectFactory<std::string , BaseFigure> figureFactory;
figureFactory.add<Square>("sq");
BaseFigure *sq = figureFactory.get("sq")();
```

I can't understand, where is error?
P.S Added Point2D and WDraw. All methods of this classes have realization.

```
class Point2d
{
public:
    Point2d(double xx, double yy);
    virtual ~Point2d(void);
    double x() const { return m_dX; }
    double y() const { return m_dY; }
private:
    double m_dX;
    double m_dY;
};
class WDraw
{    
public:
    WDraw(void);
    virtual ~WDraw(void);
    virtual void drawSegment(const Point2d& p1, const Point2d& p2);
};
```

Comment: Is that the only error message you get regarding this problem?

Comment: is `Point2d` default-constructible?

Comment: Joachim Pileborg, yes it's only.

Comment: @OkadzakiTomoe so as I thought `Point2d` is not default-constructible, hence an implcicitly defined constructor of `Square` would be ill-formed, so it's deleted

Comment: [OT]: infinite recursive call: `void Square::boundingBox(WDraw &drawer) {
        this->boundingBox(drawer);
    }`

Comment: @OkadzakiTomoe an option is to add a default constructor for `Point2d`, like `Point2d() : m_dX(0.0), m_dY(0.0) {}`

Comment: @Piotr Skotnicki Next error after: LineError LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall Square::~Square(void)" (??1Square@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall Square::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GSquare@@UAEPAXI@Z)

Comment: @OkadzakiTomoe that error means you haven't provided the definition of `~Square()`

Comment: Yes, it's help. Thank's.

Comment: This isn't C, there's no need to write `WDraw(void)` or `~WDraw(void)`. Without the `void` will do just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
classes[id] = &instantiator<Derived>;
```

sets up your instantiator to use this instantiated function:

```
static BaseFigure* instantiator() {
    return new Square();
}
```

But `Square` isn't default-constructible, because its member:

```
Point2d points[2];
```

isn't default-constructible, because it has a user-declared non-default constructor:

```
Point2d(double xx, double yy);
```

hence the error. The implicitly declared `Point2d` default constructor is declared as deleted, which makes the implicitly declared default constructor of `Square` declared as deleted as well.

To make this work, you'd have to either add a default constructor to `Point2d` or allow a way to pass in arguments through `Square`'s constructor into `points`. Probably the latter makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

Barry already answered with the root cause.  For the records, here a solution using your **very nice variable argument template** for a generic constructor:

Modified example of use:

```
GenericObjectFactory<std::string, BaseFigure, Point2d, double> figureFactory; //<===== A square could be constructed with top left point + width
figureFactory.add<Square>("sq");
BaseFigure *sq = figureFactory.get("sq")(Point2d(1.0,2.0), 2.0);  //<===== Instatiate with right arguments
```

The error message then clearly shows that the appropriate constructor isn't found.  Let's add it:

```
    Square(Point2d tl, double w) 
    { 
        points[0] = tl; 
        points[1] = Point2d(tl.x()+w, tl.y()+w); 
    }
```

The array can't unfortunately not be initialized in the mem-initializer, so Point2d needs also a default constructor. So add it, and it compiles fine !